# ¿Existe alguna incompatibilidad entre los distintos utf8/16/32_spanish_ci?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, utf-8, unicode

Me encuentro con crear una base de datos, pero me encuentro ante una duda que se las diferencias pero no sé si afecta a las bases de datos.

Yo siempre uso `utf8_spanish_ci` para crear la base de datos en cuanto al `collate` de la misma. Pero me he fijado que existe tanto el `utf16_general_ci`, como `utf32_general_ci`.

Por lo que he investigado y conozco :

- utf8 son de un byte
- utf16 son de dos a cuatro byte
- utf32 son decuatro fijos.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496340/3573779)

Pero mi duda no es el tamaño , es **¿Afectaría la entrada de datos a la misma?**
Me refiero , generará problemas con el texto , etc...

Yo supongo que no , pero se que hay ligeras modificaciones que puedan afectar a las mismas.

Comment: Yo la que utilizo siempre es `utf8_general_ci` y no me ha dado ningún problema. Sin embargo, lo pongo como comentario porque no sé si es exactamente la respuesta a tu pregunta. Por otro lado, cuando usé `utf8_spanish_ci` había algún carácter que me daba problemas. Sin embargo, no me acuerdo cual. Espero que te responda alguien que sepa más a fondo sobre las distintas codificaciones.

Comment: Gracias , todo aporte ayuda . Yo siempre uso `utf8_general_ci` , era por si aporta alguna facilidad o es cosa mía que me lo dijeron hace años y estoy desactualizado. Curiosidad que tengo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando escoges un collate como `utf8_spanish_ci`, en realidad estás especificando 2 cosas:

- El charset: `utf-8`
- El collate: `spanish_ci`

El *charset* determina cómo representar los datos internamente (los bytes), mientras que el *collate* determina las reglas que se siguen para comparar y ordenar el texto.

Referencia: [Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html).

**Charset**

De modo que para una misma cadena (por ejemplo `'abc'`), los valores y la cantidad de bytes usados para representar esa cadena internamente no serán los mismos si usas `utf8_general_ci` o `utf16_general_ci`, porque usan 2 *charsets* diferentes.

Hay 2 razones principales por la que escojerías un charset mas bien que otro en diferentes circunstancias:

- En el caso de algunos charsets, puede que no tenga la capacidad de representar ciertos carácteres, de modo que es importante escoger un charset que pueda manejar todos los carácteres que necesitas. Si usas un charset que comienza por `utf` (`utf8`, `utf16`, `utf32`, etc.), entonces puedes estar seguro que puedes manejar cualquier carácter que forma parte de Unicode.
- La cantidad de bytes usado por carácter varía entre los diferentes charsets. De modo que si deseas controlar la talla de la base de datos, es algo en qué pensar.

Generalmente, el uso de `utf-8` es favorecido porque equilibra muy bien la necesidad de manejar todos los carácteres en Unicode, pero a la vez usando un formato que reduce la cantidad de bytes que se necesita.

Para idiomas como español, `utf-8` puede representar los carácteres con un solo byte. Pero si te tocara manejar chino por ejemplo, entonces puede que se requieran mas bytes, y entonces puede que `utf16` sea más ventajoso. *(Nota: contrario a lo que pusistes en la pregunta, `utf8` no representa todos los carácteres en Unicode con un solo byte. Algunos sí, otros no.)*

**Collate**

Ahora bien, dentro de un *charset*, tienes la opción de escoger diferentes *collates*. Por ejemplo, puedes escoger entre `utf8_general_ci` y `utf8_spanish_ci`, y hasta también `utf8_spanish2_ci`. En todos estos casos, la representación interna del texto es idéntico (los bytes son iguales).

Mas bien, el efecto de escoger un diferente *collate* es que ajusta la manera cómo el texto es comparado y ordenado en tus consultas.

Por ejemplo, si el texto contiene letras como `ñ` o la doble L `ll`, usando diferentes collates vas a notar que el texto se ordena diferentemente cuando haces un `ORDER BY`.

Aquí te dejo una [demostración](http://rextester.com/FKMIHM35943) de cómo el *collate* afecta el orden del texto en MySQL.

En cuanto al efecto que tiene en la comparación de los datos (`where col = 'abc'`), no estoy al tanto de ninguna diferencia entre `utf8_general_ci` y `utf8_spanish_ci`. Pero puede que haya. Sé que hay diferencias en el caso de otros idiomas como alemán, por ejemplo.

Referencia: [Examples of the Effect of Collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-effect.html).